# How can I resolve an exception for a variable being resolved before assignment?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

This code gives an error that **number** is reference before assignment:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import threading  
import time 
global number
number = 1
class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = threadID
    def run(self):
        printFunction(self.name)
def printFunction(name):
    while number < 20: 
        number = number +1 
        print number
        print name 
thread1 = myThread(1)
thread2 = myThread(2)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

It is not about multithreading.

In `printFunction` you are accessing and manipulating the global variable `number`.

You should move `global number` statement into `printFunction` because you are manipulating a global variable inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer here mentioned, the issue isn't with your threading. It is that you are modifying a global variable without the global qualifier appearing *in the scope that the variable is being modified.* This snippet demonstrates this:

```
global_variable = 1

def access():
    # we can access a global variable without using the work "global"
    print("Value of global_variable: {}".format(global_variable))
    return

def qualified_modify():
    # we can modify a global variable if we use the "global" qualifier
    global global_variable 
    global_variable += 1

    return

def unqualified_modify():
    # we can't modify a global variable without the "global" qualifier
    # this function will cause an exception to be raised
    global_variable += 1
    return

access()
qualified_modify()
print("Incremented global variable: {}".format(global_variable))
unqualified_modify()
```

This code produces this output:

> Value of global_variable: 1
>   Incremented global variable: 2
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "global_var.py", line 23, in 
>       unqualified_modify()
>     File "global_var.py", line 17, in unqualified_modify
>       global_variable += 1

Notice that the global qualifier needs to appear in the function where the variable is accessed. It tells the interpreter to go look in the global scope *for a variable to modify*, but is not necessary just to read a global.

Since you didn't include the whole stack trace and exception message, I can't be sure, but I suspect it is pointing out the `number = number + 1` line. `while number < 20:` should be fine because the interpreter can find and *read* the global variable, but to modify it, you need to tell the interpreter that the variable is a global.